# Set Google Plus sign in button type

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

I have a Google+ sign in button on my site and I can't figure out how to set its style to one of the predefined styles on the Google+ branding guide page.
https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines

On the guideline page, the buttons are listed in a table featuring a column 'style' which has differing string values for respective buttons, ie 'Long', 'Short', etc

The button on my page is rendered in a span defined as

```
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="onSignInCallback"
    data-clientid="MY_APP_ID@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    data-approvalprompt="force"
    data-cookiepolicy="http://mysite.com"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
  </span>
```

I don't wish to make a purely custom button. Any idea where can I assign the pre-defined style?

Comment: Did you download the file shown in that table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the standard style with a combination of the following attributes:

```
data-height="standard"  (one of short, standard or tall)
data-width="standard"   (one of iconOnly, standard or wide)
data-theme="dark"       (one of light or dark)
```

These attributes are documented here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference